# Why we compare expectations sometimes and sometimes probabilities?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am reading device independent approach on quantum mechanics from here [device independent outlook on quantum mechanics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3081). In here the author introduces local variable theory. Then he give two results. First any local variable statistics can be explained by a deterministic local variable. Second some of the quantum statistics such as measurement in same basis on singlet state can be given by a deterministic local variable statistics. By statistics I mean there are two separate parties $A$ and $B$ with input sets being $x$ and $y$ respectively and output sets being $a$ and $b$ respectively. Also they share a pre-established agreement $\lambda$, and we are interested in $$P(a,b|x,y)=\int \rho(\lambda|x,y)P^{'}(a,b|x,y,\lambda)d\lambda$$ Sometimes the author says two theories give same statistics by comparing the expectations of results and sometimes he say two theories give same statistics if probability distribution for all cases is the same. Why is it so ?

Comment: Just a few remarks about quantum mysticism: within conventional quantum mechanics Bell inequalities are a tautology in the same sense that momentum and energy conservation are a tautology in classical mechanics: they are there because we put them there. From a mathematical point of view there is no point in trying to "derive" an axiom of a theory within the theory. Either the theory falls by a conclusive EXPERIMENT, or it doesn't. The paper itself looks like a collection of re-imagined facts and naive misunderstandings about QM. I would disregard it and look for something with substance.

Comment: @CuriousOne I am just a beginner in quantum mechanics so I don't have a broad idea about it. But I feel disregard is a strong comment. I have come across a lot on bell polytopes. Even on the forum experienced users ask questions about it for example here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8514/bell-polytopes-with-nontrivial-symmetries. Keeping your point in my mind I will give it a try and see for myself whether the paper/topic is reasonable.

Comment: I am just trying to put these kinds of articles in the context of the definition of science for you. You can disregard it and chase this tail as long as you wish... eventually you will notice that a simple look at the definitions of "science" and "theory" would have lead you to the same conclusion that I just gave you. Einstein said it best: "We can not solve our problems with the same level of thinking that created them.", but that is exactly what quantum mysticism is trying to do.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I have to disagree. From what I know about the buzzwords in the abstract, what people are really trying to do is twofold: First, they consider theories that are NOT quantum mechanics but seem to also describe at least some quantum experiments and try to argue that these theories are not worth pursuing - one way to do that is to prove that the Bell inequalities are different. You can argue that this was to be expected and I would agree that a lot of the "Foundations of Quantum Mechanics" is rather weird mysticism, but it is not completely without substance.

Comment: Second, this is about "device independent tests". Such things are usually rather uninteresting from a scientific perspective, but they are very intersting from a cryptographic/engineering perspective: Given a box that tells you it outputs two maximally entangled states, how can you be sure that it actually does this? Maximal violation of a Bell inequality in my own lab would be one naive way.

Comment: @Martin: the only way to "consider" a theory that is not standard QM is experimentally. Please take a look at the quality of model building and experimental work that has been done in high energy physics and then compare that to quantum mysticism. Actually, there is no comparison. The both are worlds apart. Putting a few lasers, mirrors and wave plates together is not how quantum mechanics will be falsified. It's your homework assignment to tell me why. If you don't know that purely based on undergrad phenomenology, then you are already hopelessly caught up in circular thinking.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Maybe I didn't express myself properly, so let's just say I agree that the output of what you call Quantum mysticism is not much - at least from my uninformed point of view. Much of it is rather metaphysical wondering (I don't say all, because I simply don't know it all) - but my main point was anyway that not everything about this paper is metaphysical wondering, but some of it can be useful albeit maybe more in an engineering context.

Comment: @Martin: a good physics paper doesn't contain ANY "metaphysical wondering" and it should contain a far smaller number of obvious trivial problems with physical ontology. I will repeat my suggestion: if you want to see serious physics that actually does advance the field, look somewhere else. There are people who know how to do this right and they have published high quality papers.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Agreed. I haven't read it, but I also wouldn't. I just felt you were disregarding about everything in it completely (in combination with all the engineering related aspects) and I felt that was too harsh. Just out of curiosity, whom would you recommend to read in this particular field?

Comment: @Martin: I would suggest reading papers that make constructive experimental suggestions for the analysis of long distance interference of optical and high energy photons. We know that light propagates across the entire visible universe. Do we know if such "old light" is still capable of interference? Some experiments seem to suggest that interference (which is synonymous with the validity of quantum mechanics) is unchanged even over cosmic distances. If that is true, it seems to me that lab size experiments don't stand a chance of finding deviations from standard QM.